# When requiring new package, composer doesn't response

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

When I require any new package with composer, such as `"composer require jms/payment-core-bundle"` composer doesn't respond, it simply stops running.

I have attached a screenshot below:

[image: See screenshot of shell session]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try adding -vvv to see where it hangs

Comment: In addition to Norman's suggestion,  double check if you have `XDebug` enabled. It slows down `composer` considerably...

Comment: What happens when you remove `composer.lock` and `/vendor` and then run your command?

Comment: @NormanM doesn't response too :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, the problem has been solved.
It was a memory problem.